# High CPU usage with a Websocket Proxy using Undertow

Tags: java, websocket, proxy, reverse-proxy, undertow

I have created a Proxy using Java's Undertow library, which redirects users websocket connections to different ports in the same computer.

The problem is that with only 200 or 300 WebSockets connections the program starts to use a huge amount of CPU.

I've attached JProfiler to the application, and all the threads are either in waiting or network IO state.

The proxy server is started in the following way:

```
 Undertow reverseProxy = Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpListener(80, "0.0.0.0")
            .addHttpsListener(443, "0.0.0.0", sslContext)
            .setIoThreads(4)
            .setHandler(new ProxyHandler(reverseProxyServer, encodingHandler))
            .build();
    reverseProxy.start();
```

I'm thinking that it may be a problem of configuration, because I don't think such a CPU usage is normal.

[Threads screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUR9c.png) (yellow is waiting, light blue is net io, green is running)

[Cpu methods screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DLHz.png)

[Top screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvdCV.png)

EDIT:
I've found out that the Proxy CPU, that usually stays around 30% CPU usage, goes to almost 100% in random periods, in which one of the IO threads starts having a lot of runnable action, see screenshots:

[Threads 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp9Gz.png)

[Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SES8i.png)

Comment: "all the threads are either in waiting or network IO state." If that is true, then the CPU load cannot be high - except if other programs consume CPU time. I would try a different computer to be sure that it is not a hardware/driver issue. By the way: 300 open sockets is a lot. Most servers that I saw process less than 50 connections simultaneously.

Comment: @Stefan you can check the screenshots to see the threads and methods. "top" command on Linux reports a high CPU usage from the program, sometimes as high as 80% or more.
When the sockets are connected directly to the endpoint programs (without a proxy), the CPU usage is normal on them. But when done through the Proxy, the Proxy's CPU usage is much higher.

Comment: I can't see your screenshot from "top".

Comment: I've currently limited the user amount so CPU usage is now on around 25%. Is there any specific part of top that you would like to see?

Comment: I would like to see which program causes the high CPU load and how much memory it uses because your screenshots do not answer your question. A simple screenshot from the default view of "top" would be fine for the moment.

Comment: I added a top screenshot, the pid 25052 is the proxy, the other Java processes are game servers, on the top of the screens is the overall CPU usage.
The proxy has more CPU usage than 2 of the game servers, which other that managing WebSockets connections also have to do a lot of other logic.
PS: The CPU usage in the main game server is that high because I released the user limit. I want to see if I can reproduce the almost 80% cpu usage on the proxy.

Comment: Maybe your garbage collector is very active, can you check that?

Comment: JProfiler shows it with an activity of between 0 and 1%, in the logs I see a small collection (User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s) every around 700ms. So it shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: Yes right, 1% garbage collector is Ok. So I don't see any reason for the high CPU load.